# AndEngine with Physics PhysicsFactory error

Tags: android, andengine

When I try to run andengine examples I get this problem:

```
The method createBoxBody(PhysicsWorld, IShape, BodyDef.BodyType, FixtureDef) from the type PhysicsFactory refers to the missing type IShape
```

On this line:

```
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
```

and this error:

```
The method registerUpdateHandler(IUpdateHandler) in the type Entity is not applicable for the arguments (PhysicsWorld)
```

On this line:

```
this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
```

Thanks

Comment: Make sure that you are not linking different versions of AndEngine and AndEnineExamples together. Are you using the latest versions from the GIT repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The solution was to make AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension-GLES2 have AndEngine-GLES2 as a module dependency in IntelliJ.